# Kendo Popup undefined anchor

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am having some issues implementing the click away functionality of Kendo UIs popup as described here: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/popup/closing/

My code flow is that the [anchor] that is used for the actual filter popup is defined in the container. Nontheless, I am sure that is not part of the issue. My component file (relevant parts):

```
@ViewChild("anchor", { read: ElementRef}) public anchor: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild("popup", { read: ElementRef }) public popup: ElementRef;

    @HostListener("keydown", ["$event"])
    public keydown(event: any): void {
        if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        this.onToggle(false);
        }
    }

    @HostListener("document:click", ["$event"])
    public documentClick(event: any): void {
        if (!this.contains(event.target)) {
        this.onToggle(false);
        }
    }

private contains(target: any): boolean {
        return (
          this.anchor?.nativeElement?.contains(target) ||
          (this.popup ? this.popup.nativeElement.contains(target) : false)
        );
      }
public onToggle(show? : boolean): void {
        this.show = show ?? !this.show;
    }
```

Html:

```
<button  #anchor (click)="onToggle()" mat-raised-button color="list-button">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxLayoutGap="10px">
        <fa-icon [icon]="faFilter" class="fa-sm"></fa-icon>
        <div>Filter</div>
    </div>
</button>
<div class="kendo-override-popup mimick-material-popup">
    <kendo-popup #popup [popupAlign]="popupAlign" [anchorAlign]="anchorAlign"
        [anchor]="inputAnchor" [type]="slide" [margin]="margin" *ngIf="show">   

...
```

The issue boils down to clicking the button properly triggers the toggle, however the document click event then fires and it always returns false for contains, thus it then automatically closes the dropdown as well. I ran the example kendo has in stackblitz and their view child elements exist just fine, for me the anchor is always undefined regardless of where I put, or if I have it read element ref or not

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more browsing and looking at other SO questions relating to undefined ViewChildren I've come across this solution for my issue:

1. Wrap the whole component in a `div`
2. Give said div an identifier, ex: `#wrapper`
3. Update code to be like so:

@ViewChildren("wrapper") public wrapper: any;

```
private contains(target: any): boolean {

        let button = this.wrapper?.first?.nativeElement?.children[0] as HTMLButtonElement;

        return (
           button.contains(target) ||
          //this.anchor?.nativeElement?.contains(target) ||
          (this.popup ? this.popup.nativeElement.contains(target) : false)
        );
      }
```

This works because we know what our html layout is like, and thus we are quite assured that element[0] is an html button element. It is not the prettiest approach, but it works